# Unable to add new keys in an object from redux store using immutable js

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

How can I add a new key to an object in redux store using immutable js? For eg. I have a chartdata key inside my state which is an empty object to start with. I am making calls to get chart data. My reducer gets a `chartId` and a `data` array after the call is done. I just want to add a new key with `chartId` and set the value as `data`. So as my calls will proceed, the `chartdata` will look something like this:

```
chartdata: {
    "123" : [{}, {}],
    "324" : [{}, {}],
... }
```

I tried the following code:

```
return state.setIn(['chartData', action.chartId], action.data);
```

expecting it to create a new key as chartId if it is not found, and update the data if it already exists.

I am getting the following error in my browser console:

```
uncaught at getChartDataSaga Error: invalid keyPath
at invariant (webpack:///./~/immutable/dist/immutable.js?:872:27)
at updateInDeepMap (webpack:///./~/immutable/dist/immutable.js?:1976:5)
at updateInDeepMap (webpack:///./~/immutable/dist/immutable.js?:1982:23)
at Map.updateIn (webpack:///./~/immutable/dist/immutable.js?:1280:26)
at Map.setIn (webpack:///./~/immutable/dist/immutable.js?:1258:19)
at chartsReducer (eval at ./app/modules/Library/Charts/reducer.js (http://localhost:3000/14.chunk.js:15:1), <anonymous>:26:20)
at eval (webpack:///./~/redux-immutable/dist/combineReducers.js?:37:39)
at Array.forEach (native)
at eval (webpack:///./~/redux-immutable/dist/combineReducers.js?:34:25)
at Map.withMutations (webpack:///./~/immutable/dist/immutable.js?:1355:7)
```

Comment: How did you initialize your data? Did you do `Map(state)` or `fromJS(state)`?

Comment: fromJS(state). I realized that later and was able to use the correct API.